# How to pass parameter to Dataview Webpart without refersh

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I would like to pass spme parameters using QueryString asper normal to a a listview or DWP.
But i don't want the page to refersh.I tried using hash which works but no idea i can  pass the parameter to my DWP.
THanks in advance

My snippet code below.

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () { 

checkSelected(); 
});



function checkSelected() {
    var m = $('#dropdown').find("option:selected").val();

    if (m !== 'Choose') {

        //This works but reloads the page
        var url = "?s=" + m;
        window.location.href = url;

        //This doesn't do any postback but doesn't refersh DWP
        //window.location.hash = "?store=" + m;

       //var param = document.URL.split('#')[1];
       //alert(param);

       //return false;


    }

  }
```